# I want to create an add button

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in excel and I really need a button that if pressed adds a certain value to the cells I selected, is that possible?

Comment: What did you find after you did your research? It seems possible to me.

Comment: I Don't know yet

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to add the certain value? You're more likely to get an answer if you can show what you've tried - have a read of [ASK] and [MCVE].

Comment: I have but failed, I have searched and now I can change the value of selected cells. But I still can't add a value to the value of the selected cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered me in two minutes on another site with this perfect code for what I wanted, thanks a lot sir. It works like magic.

Sub Add_to_Selection()
If Not IsNumeric([E4]) Then
Exit Sub
Else
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Selection
cell.Value = cell.Value + [E4].Value
Next cell
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can add buttons to Excel by enabling developer mode:

- On the File tab, go to Options > Customize Ribbon.
- Under Customize the Ribbon and under Main Tabs, select the Developer check box.

Then on the developer ribbon you can click insert, then select a button to draw onto the sheet.

You will then be given the option to assign a macro to the button (Also later accessible by right clicking the button).

As for the VBA code of the macro, you would need to be more specific about what functionality you require, is the 'certain value' to be added to the selected cells always the same value?

Comment: Yes the same value predefined in another cell, ty for the quick response

Comment: No answer yet? Please I need an answer!